# fopen what is the b flag

Tags: php, file-io, fopen

In reading the [documentation for php fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for php I see the following:

> For portability, it is strongly recommended that you always use the 'b' flag when opening files with [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)().

What is the `b` flag and what does it do ?
Why is it strongly recommended ?

Comment: It gives more information on above note of the one you have stated. It forces binary mode.  "If you do not specify the 'b' flag when working with binary files, you may experience strange problems with your data, including broken image files and strange problems with \r\n characters. "

Comment: @Ekn why not an answer? :)

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser Alright, added as an answer but at first I actually thought maybe I should flag the question as the answer was kind of within the question itself :p

Comment: Everything is explained in the *Note* above the *Note* you quoted in your questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 'b' flag forces binary mode.

You use the 'b' flag if you want to deal with binary files, ie. an image.

> **Note:**
>
> When you write a text file and want to insert a line break, you need to use the correct line-ending character(s) for your operating system.
>
> Unix based systems use `\n` as the line ending character, Windows based systems use `\r\n` as the line ending characters and Macintosh based systems use `\r` as the line ending character.
>
> Windows offers a text-mode translation flag ('t') which will transparently translate `\n` to `\r\n` when working with the file.
>
> **In contrast, you can also use 'b' to force binary mode, which will not translate your data.**

You can avoid the translation by using the 'b' flag in the `mode` parameter. Example usage:

```
$handle_read  = fopen($filepath, 'rb');

$handle_write = fopen("/home/user/file.gif", "wb");
```

So... the reason this is recommended is clearly stated on the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> If you do not specify the 'b' flag when working with binary files, you may experience strange problems with your data, including broken image files and strange problems with \r\n characters.

The usage of 'b' flag is also noted on manual pages of `fwrite()` and `fread()` which are binary-safe file read/write functions.

> **Warning:**
>
> On systems which differentiate between binary and text files (i.e. Windows) the file must be opened with 'b' included in fopen() mode parameter.

```
$filename = "c:\\files\\somepic.gif";
$handle   = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: The documentation does not seam clear. It sounds like I should be doing this for both text and binary files. It seams like I should only be doing for binary files like images or audio.