# Only 14 bytes are uploaded into Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to upload some files into Google Cloud Storage using PHP. It seems to be partially working, since I'm seeing the files in the web console, however I've noticed that all files are only 14 bytes in size, while the original is much bigger.

This is the code I'm using:

```
/**
 *
 */
public static function saveFile($originalFile, $newFilename) {

    $bucket = MyStorage::getBucket();

    if ($bucket == null) {

        // Save locally
        Storage::disk('local')->put(FileController::$FILE_DIR . $newFilename, file_get_contents($originalFile));

    } else {

        // Save to Google Cloud Platform
        $bucket->upload($originalFile->getRealPath(), ['name' => $newFilename]);

    }
}

/**
 *
 */
private static function getBucket() {

    $appEnv = getenv('APP_ENV');

    if ($appEnv == "production" || $appEnv == "test") {

        $GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID = getenv('GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID');
        $GOOGLE_CLOUD_BUCKET_NAME = getenv('GOOGLE_BUCKET_NAME');

        $storage = new StorageClient(['projectId' => $GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID]);
        $bucket = $storage->bucket($GOOGLE_CLOUD_BUCKET_NAME);

        return $bucket;

    } else {

        return null;
    }
}
```

`$originalFile->getRealPath()` returns something like `/tmp/asdfasdfadf` and I've verified that that file exists and is a reasonable size. The `$newFilename` variable name is what I want it to be stored as and this part seems to work as I'm seeing that filename in the web console.

Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: I don't really know php, but is it possible that you're only uploading the path to the file as a string, as opposed to the actual file? If you look at the client library, they seem to use `fopen`: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.24.0/storage/bucket?method=upload 
ie `$bucket->upload( fopen($originalFile->getRealPath(), 'r'), ['name' => $newFilename]);`

Comment: you can change the upload of maximum allowed size in php.ini.serch this upload_max_filesize = 128M

Comment: @RobertLacok good catch, I'll check that out and report back.

Comment: @RobertLacok you were correct. Care to make this an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're only uploading the path to the file as a string, as opposed to the actual file.

If you look at the client library, [they seem to use `fopen`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.24.0/storage/bucket?method=upload)

`$bucket->upload( fopen($originalFile->getRealPath(), 'rb'), ['name' => $newFilename]);`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my bug.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for using file upload, you need to read the stream of bytes to send it to remote cloud. fopen will do this job for you, to create stream of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
else {

    // Save to Google Cloud Platform
    $bucket->upload($originalFile->getRealPath(), ['name' => $newFilename]);

}
```

Should be:

```
else {

    // Save to Google Cloud Platform
    $bucket->upload(fopen($originalFile->getRealPath(), 'rb'), ['name' => $newFilename]);

    if( fclose($originalFile->getRealPath()) === false){
       // Success
    } else{
       // Failure
    }


}
```

The reason that your code didn't work is because you were uploading only the filename to Google Cloud. "/tmp/asdfasd" is 14 characters.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660282/fopen-what-is-the-b-flag) is an answer on why the 'b' is important for the fopen command.

FClose closes the resource, preventing data leaks. Also, check the return value from fclose(), as some OS only flush file output. Checking the return value can save severe data leaks.